# GROUP BY WiTH one column and show multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table bschool_test_relation_domain with columns testid,courseid,instid

```
  instid | Courseid  | testid
  23     |   35      | 45
  23     |   35      | 56
  33     |   45      | 68
  33     |   45      | 76
  33     |   45      | 86
```

I need to fetch the row with group by inst_id and CourseID and then check  the testid to filter the data.

```
 Select t1,instid,t1.courseid  
   from table1 as t1 
   JOIN 
      ( Select instid 
             , courseid 
          from bschool_test_relation_domain 
         group 
            by instid 
             , courseid ) t2 
     ON t2.instid = t1.instid 
    AND t2.courseid = t1.courseid 
  where t2.testid = 68
```

result I want is

```
  instid | Courseid  | testid
  33     |   45      | 68
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: share your expected result

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: instId is the primary key

Comment: sorry in table1 instid is the primary key, In bschool_test_relation_domain  it is testid

Comment: where is your table1 data @BLPraveen

Comment: It's still not clear why you want 68 as opposed to 86 (or 76)

Comment: I have added the columns

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: We need more sample data for both tables, with several different instid values. And the matching expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using `min()`

```
Select instid , courseid,min(testid)
from bschool_test_relation_domain 
where instid = 33
group by instid , courseid
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function `min()` no need any subquery

```
select  b.instid , b.courseid ,min(b.testid) testid
          from bschool_test_relation_domain b
           join table1 t on b.courseid=t.courseid and b.instid=t.instid
           where t.testid = 33
group by b.instid , b.courseid
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the below one i hope this will works:

```
Select instid , courseid
from bschool_test_relation_domain
where orderby testid
```